# What is the way to say that something is common, believed, advised?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

What is the way to say that something is common, recommended, advised?

I've come up with the following phrase:

> **It's considered** that a good developer must know algorithms.

Is it idiomatic?

Comment: "Generally considered" is more common, as in "It's generally considered that a good developer must know algorithms".

Comment: Grammatically that is OK. The problem with using the passive mood in such constructions is that it obscures the question  "who considers this?" and that might be a very bad thing if it is used to duck responsibility for a highly contentious statement such as "it is considered that women are not able to become physicists of the highest class" - I have deliberately chosen an extreme and extremely offensive example to illustrate that the passive may be used to sound authoritative about something that is just not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some alternatives for your consideration:

> "It is commonly held that a good developer must know algorithms."
>
> "The general belief is that a good developer must know algorithms."
>
> "It is generally believed that a good developer must know algorithms."
>
> "Most consider that a good developer must know algorithms."
>
> "Most expect a good developer to know algorithms."
>
> "A good developer is generally expected to know algorithms."

Comment: Also, "It's considered common sense that a good developer must know algorithms"